# TypeError: can only assign an iterable - Values to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can you sugggest a way to apply the value of a variable to a list from element 6 to end defined by a variable?

Maybe my code will explain it better (Python 3)

```
#get user input as to size of range
range_size = 0
if range_size == 0:
    try:
        range_size = int(input('Size of Range?: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('That was not an integer!')
        range_size = 0

#set base value for each number in range_size
base_value = int(100 / range_size)

print(base_value)

#create list of base values
num_weighted = [base_value] * range_size
num_weighted[0] = round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
num_weighted[1] = round(base_value * 1.6, 1)
num_weighted[2] = round(base_value * 1.5, 1)
num_weighted[3] = round(base_value * 1.3, 1)
num_weighted[4] = round(base_value * 1.15, 1)
num_weighted[5] = round(base_value * 1.1, 1)

print(num_weighted)
# redistribute the difference of the sum top 6 and 100, apply to rest of range
top6 = (sum(num_weighted[0:6]))
not_top6 = range_size - 6
pts_alloc = round((100 - top6) / not_top6, 1)
print(pts_alloc)

#attempt 1
num_weighted[6:] = pts_alloc

#attempt 2
#num_weighted[6:(range_size + 1)] = pts_alloc

#attempt 3
#s = slice(6, not_top6)
#num_weighted[s] = pts_alloc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a list of `pts_alloc` and assign it to the slice like this

```
num_weighted[6:] = [pts_alloc for i in range(len(num_weighted) - 6)]
```

Comment: Even simpler: `num_weighted[6:] = [pts_alloc]*(len(num_weighted)-6)`

Comment: @thefourtheye: The same reference to what?

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.append()`:

```
num_weighted.append(pts_alloc)
```

You can only assign an iterable to a slice; something with 0 or more values, not one specific value.

I'd not pre-build the list then replace everything; just do:

```
num_weighted = [
    round(base_value * 1.8, 1)
    round(base_value * 1.6, 1)
    round(base_value * 1.5, 1)
    round(base_value * 1.3, 1)
    round(base_value * 1.15, 1)
    round(base_value * 1.1, 1)
]
```

and extend the list with `pts_alloc` using `list.extend()` with a generator:

```
num_weighted.extend(pts_alloc for _ in range(range_size - 6))
```

Now you have a list of length `range_size`.

Comment: Just to be clear as my example may not I want the pts_alloc applied to every list entry from the 6th entry to the end(defined by range_size - 6)

Comment: You have only 6 values in the list, and `pts_alloc` is a single number, in which case `.append()` is the right way to add that single value to the list.

Comment: @sayth: but if you need to add the same value, repeated, you have to provide the value repeated enough times to fill up the right count. Python doesn't have a pre-set size for the list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters     okay, just figuring it out, my list has 12 entries not 6 at the point I am trying to overwrite the values of 6:(to the end) with the same value

Comment: Ah, yes. But why are you pre-filling a list, then replacing every single value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  perhaps bad logic but I want to ensure I have the correct size for range. As this will be list 1 and I plan to sum the indexes of a set of lists by position. list1[0] + list2[0] etc and I am lerning python and thats the way I thought i could remain consistent.